# Not receiving all messages at receiver lambda from SQS with AWS serverless and NodeJS

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, serverless

We created two lamdba functions using AWS Serverless and NodeJS one is sender and other is receiver, and in between these two there in one Standard SQS which is receiving data from sender lambda and it automatically triggers the receiver lambda function if any message arrives at SQS.

Here, we are able to send all messages successfully from sender lambda to SQS(as per the logs), but at receiver lambda we are not getting all the messages.

To test this scenario I sent 1000 messages from postman and tested that sender was sending all messages perfectly to SQS, but receiver was only getting random 986 messages out of it, some random messages have been missed in between.

**I also tried the SQS type to FIFO instead of standard but it is not supported by lambda.**

Here is the code for sender and receiver function:

SENDER:

```
sender: () => {
    const sqs = new AWS.SQS({ apiVersion: "2019-08-09" });
    let body = [
        { id : "1" },
        { id : "2" },
        { id : "3" }
    ]
    let params = {
        DelaySeconds: 10,
        QueueUrl: url,
        MessageBody: JSON.stringify(body)
    };
    sqs.sendMessage(params, function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            callback(true, null);
        } else {
            callback(false, data);
        }
    });
}
```

RECEIVER :

```
receiver: () => {
    event.Records[0].body = JSON.parse(event.Records[0].body);
    async.timesSeries(event.Records[0].body.length, (i, next) => {
        const params = {
            TableName: "user",
            Key: {
                id: "1"
            }
        };
        dynamoDb.get(params).promise()
            .then(result => {
                //save user
            })
            .catch(error => {
                //throw err
                next();
            });
    }, () => {
        console.log("deleting message");
        const deleteParams = {
            QueueUrl: "queue_url",
            ReceiptHandle: event.Records[0].receiptHandle
        };
        sqs.deleteMessage(deleteParams, function (err, data) {
            if (err) {
                //throw error
            } else {
                //success
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: did you find any solution?

Answer (score 4):

In this code:

```
event.Records[0].body = JSON.parse(event.Records[0].body);
async.timesSeries(event.Records[0].body.length, (i, next) => {
```

By explicitly taking `Records[0]` you are only processing the first record in the list. `event.Records` is a list, and you need to iterate over all records in the list. See an example SQS event in the documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sqs.html) that includes multiple records.

---

Alternatively, in your Lambda SQS integration settings, change the **Batch Size** to `1` so that only `1` record at a time will be passed to your Lambda function.

Comment: Hi Mark,

Thanks for your quick response.

I have checked it and have added console on first line of receiver and found that it is not even printing that console for few messages.

receiver: () => {
    console.log("first line");
    event.Records[0].body = JSON.parse(event.Records[0].body);
}

Comment: @Anshul I don't know how that would be possible for the Lambda function to be invoked but somehow not execute the first line of code. How do you know it isn't printing "for some messages"? What is your `Batch Size` setting? Also, you shouldn't be deleting the messages in your code, you should be returning a success response which will trigger the Lambda SQS integration to delete the message for you.